# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu messes up WiFi

Tags: networking, linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, cinnamon

I have installed Windows 10 on my desktop and have then also installed Mint OS (Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon [5.8.4] to be specific). Before I installed Mint, both WiFi and Ethernet were working perfectly on Windows. Now, Windows is unable to connect to Ethernet or WiFi (with the exception of mobile hot spots), and Mint is only able to connect to WiFi (including hot spots) but no Ethernet.
The similar cases to this that I have seen have always been that Ubuntu is unable to connect, so I am unable to use any of the previous solutions. I have updated all the drivers on Windows, without success.
Additionally, I had this same issue several months ago, and I removed Ubuntu to get rid of it, so I do not believe that it is an issue with a recent update or anything of the like.
I am not entirely certain what technical specifications are helpful in finding a solution to this, so for now I will merely note that my motherboard is a 'ROG STRIX X570-E GAMING WIFI II'.

Comment: Does it work if you power off (rather than just warm boot) between changing operating systems?

Comment: @user10489 Thank you: your suggestion was partially more helpful than I could have expected. I had been warm booting to Windows and, now having booted directly to it and then changed some settings around, it will now connect to WiFi no matter which OS I boot to first. That said, ethernet still is not working; Windows says no internet and Mint is stuck on 'connecting...'. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cold booting the machine between operating systems sometimes helps with problems like this.

The issue is that the driver for the other operating system may initialize the device in a way that the current operating system doesn't know how to undo.  Technically, it is possible to power cycle the device rather than the whole machine, but it is difficult (but not impossible) to write a script to do this at boot, and it would be a bad idea to have the driver do this automatically.  Typically it's easier to just not warm boot.

Further debugging would be necessary to determine why ethernet is not working.  This could be an external problem (like a bad cable). Mint should eventually time out the network interface.  It should be possible to mark the network interface as hotplug so the system doesn't wait for it at boot, which would make diagnostics a lot easier.